# Multigrid method: linear solver and modified residual

Tags: linear-algebra, fluid-dynamics, algorithms, multigrid

I am trying to better understand the FAS multigrid algorithm for Euler equation in FV discretization. The usage of the modified residual (the residual with forcing) inside the different cases:

- **Unsteady computations** : referring to the [Jameson's paper](http://aero-comlab.stanford.edu/Papers/Multigrid.pdf) I understand that it is used in the dual time step computation that allows for a faster convergence. This fact seems confirmed by [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01182415/), where a similar approach is used.
- **Steady computations**: if I have well understood (seen that there is not the time integration) is used in the linear solver process, hence for example with a [Krylov based method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov_subspace).

I wanted to ask if these two points are correct, and, in the second case, if we have to rely compulsorily on a Krylov based method (e.g [GMRES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_minimal_residual_method)). From my understanding another solver (e.g [Jacobi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method)) would not take into account the modified residual with forcing and so would not take into account the history of the different multigrid levels residual, making the multigrid algorithm ineffective.